# How to left-justify the title of UIActionSheet

Tags: iphone, uiactionsheet

Is it possible to left-justify the `title` text of a `UIActionSheet`? Thanks!

Comment: Yes it is possible http://stackoverflow.com/a/25602552/2459296

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to customize the `title` of an `UIActionSheet`. If you want something similar, you will have to design your own clone.

Comment: @Salim, I don't recommend enumerating the private subviews of system classes; they can and will change in future versions of iOS.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use spaces after the name that you set for a button in UIActionsheet. For example if it is @"download" you can change to @"Download------------" which dashes here are spaces.

I hope it works.

Comment: There are too many different kinds of screens for this to ever work

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can do it.

```
NSArray *subViewArray = yourActionSheet.subviews;
for(int x=0;x<[subViewArray count];x++){
    if([[[subViewArray objectAtIndex:x] class] isSubclassOfClass:[UILabel class]])
    {
        UILabel *label = [subViewArray objectAtIndex:x];
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    }

}
```

Comment: yes, it works. I have it working in one app of mine right now. Do you see any error message?

Comment: No, there is no error message. The labels are still centered.

Comment: this is strange. I have it working here. Are you compiling for iOS 6?

Comment: It seems the subviews of a UIAlertSheet are UIAlertButtons, which are a subclass of UIButton, not UILabel. UIAlertButton contains a UIAlertLabel, which is a subclass of UILabel. If you nail down to that and create a UILabel... I can successfully print out the button titles, but it does not change the textAlignment.. hmm.. looks like im making table with custom cells.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible

```
- (void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet {
    [actionSheet.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id _currentView, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if ([_currentView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            ((UIButton *)_currentView).contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
            ((UIButton *)_currentView).contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 30, 0, 0);
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Have you gotten this into app store?

Comment: Yes, now the app is in app store. Thanks