# Not able to align button text in UIActionSheet for iphone5

Tags: objective-c

How to align button text in UIActionSheet for iPhone5?

Comment: What do you mean by align? Post some sample code

Comment: UIActionSheet *actionsheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Send a text message." delegate:(id)self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Message",nil ];------for cancelButtonTitle I want to align it as left..

Comment: **Answer:** http://stackoverflow.com/a/25602552/2459296

Answer (score 0):

Using this way,you can set frame,change font as well as alignment of the button text on your actionsheet.

```
CGRect oldFrame = [(UILabel*)[[sheet subviews] objectAtIndex:0] frame];
UILabel *newTitle = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:oldFrame] autorelease];
newTitle.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
newTitle.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
newTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
newTitle.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
newTitle.text = @"Your Title";
[sheet addSubview:newTitle];

[sheet release];
```

Comment: UIActionSheet *actionsheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Send a text message." delegate:(id)self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Message",nil ];------for cancelButtonTitle I want to align it as left..

Comment: that is what i've shown in my answer. put a label on cancel button index. and align the text however you want.